# Confusion with Org-Wide Defaults Permission and Profile

Tags: permissions, profile, standard-objects, org-wide-defaults

I have two users .. attached is the screenshot[image]

The object level permission on "Job Application" object is:
[image]

The Org-Wide record level access on "Job Application" object is:
[image]

Now what is happening is that when I am logging as "Paromita Deb", I am able to see all the records which are not own by Paromita Deb like below:
[image]

But while logging as "Pradipta Deb", I am not able to see any records as there is no Job Application owned by "Pradipta Deb".

My question is how come then "Paromita Deb" is able to see "Job Applications" created by "Sudipta Deb".
Please help me to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you click into the records that she can see but doesn't own and check how the record is shared. This should show you what is giving her permissions to see the record.

Comment: The owner can change and it can be different than the Created By. So log in with the Pradipta Deb user and check the owner of those records. Also check sharing rules as @jjbennett530 said

Comment: Also, we need to know how the roles are set up, because the org wide defaults include role sharing.

Comment: If you see, paromita deb has the role of a CEO. So it should have been the highest role. As @sfdcfox insisted, you need to know how the roles are set up, because the org wide defaults include role sharing.

Comment: @varunguruvugari: Thanks. You are correct. The problem was due to Paromita deb had the role of a CEO. Once I changed the role, it is now working as expected.